# "debian apt-get install" to install newer version of a certain package other than the default one 5 years old

Tags: debian, apt-get

How to use "debian apt-get install" to download the newest available version of a certain package other than one years old but without changing system-wide settings/sources.list?

for example "apt-get install gddrescue" will get the version of 2009 
from the official sources http://packages.debian.org/en/squeeze/gddrescue

but i need a newer one of 2011 and 2012  ( http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddrescue/?C=M;O=D and bet the official sources know of one of them just labeled them experimental still)

i imagine something that ideally would be like
"apt-get install gddrescue version:1.15"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt-get just donwloads and installs whatever they have listed as the current .deb for that program. If you need a newer version it would be faster to get the source code from the programs website and compile it yourself. Most programs have a simple download, extract, make, make install procedure and its good to go.